# Android Radio Button Group, why I need this?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

Why i need to add **if (null != rb && checkedId > -1)**, if I remove the code, the program still work. What's the benefit of this line of code?

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if (null != rb && checkedId > -1) {

                switch (rb.getId()){

                    case R.id.radioFast:
                        mAnimOption = FAST;
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioSlow:
                        mAnimOption = SLOW;
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioNone:
                        mAnimOption = NONE;
                        break;


                }
                // End switch block

                mEditor.putInt("anim option", mAnimOption);

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: no need to use this line.it will check only selection and selected id of radio group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benefit is to avoid nullpointerexception which can cause your android app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (null != rb && checkedId > -1)
```

it is used to avoid crashes, so thar whenever NULL is invoked or user checkedId is NULL it throws error, and avoid unwanted crashes.

As per Developer, we should make code in this way no crashes are appearing during run of APP.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers says it is required to avoid `NullPointerException` I agree with them.

But as per your code it's not required. You don't need to check for the `null`. Here's why?

The method

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {}
```

returns `group` object of type `RadioGroup` and currently selected `RadioButton` id as `checkedId`. Hence you don't need to check for the null as you already have `checkedId`.

So directly use `switch` statement to compare between expected cases.

If `checkedId` is not matching with cases (i.e, -1 or other value) use `default` case.